# unexpected input in R

Tags: r

I am trying to add columns to my df for woba, an advanced baseball stat, but when I try to mutate the column it gives an unexpected input.

This is my code

```
library(baseballr)
output <- bref_daily_batter("2015-05-10", "2015-05-30")
output <- mutate(output, wOBA = (0.687*uBB + 0.718*HBP + 0.881*X1B + 1.256*X2B + 1.594*X3B + 2.065*HR) / (AB + BB – IBB + SF + HBP))
```

> Error: unexpected input in "output<- mutate(output, wOBA = (0.687*uBB + 0.718*HBP + 0.881*X1B + 1.256*X2B + 1.594*X3B + 2.065*HR) / (AB + BB –"

Comment: Replace `–` with an actual `-`. Have you copied that code from a word document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in whatever negative symbol you are using.

This does not work:

```
output <- mutate(output, wOBA = (0.687*uBB + 0.718*HBP + 0.881*X1B + 1.256*X2B + 1.594*X3B + 2.065*HR) / (AB + BB – IBB + SF + HBP))
```

but this does:

```
output <- mutate(output, wOBA = (0.687*uBB + 0.718*HBP + 0.881*X1B + 1.256*X2B + 1.594*X3B + 2.065*HR) / (AB + BB - IBB + SF + HBP))
```

I just replaced the minus sign with a new minus sign, which looks slightly smaller on my screen